# Find the lengths of each side of an obtuse triangle given the perimeter

Tags: linear-algebra

A triangular plot has sides of 3 different lengths. The longest side is three times the length of the shortest side. The 'middle-sized' side is 10m shorter than the longest side. The perimeter of the plot is 900m. How do I go about finding the lengths of the sides?

EDIT: Not a right-angled triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be a right triangle. Let $x<y<z$ be the side lenghts. We have $z=3x$, $y=z-10$ and $x+y+z=900$, so $x+3x-10+3x=900 \Rightarrow 7x = 910 \Rightarrow x=130$. This means that the sides are $x=130$, $y=380$ and $z=390$. Since $390^2 < 380^2 + 130^2$, the triangle is actually obtuse.

Comment: edited to correct. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are three conditions to solve for three sides, solved by João Miranda Gondim. No need to impose an incompatible constraint of  a right triangle... which can be removed.